# Add ACF shortcode to URL

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to add a custom field to the url submission link for my form using the an ACF shortcode, however it does not retrieve the value which I have input.

Would appreciate any help. Below is my form with the [acf field="input" on line 6.

```
     <form class="ng-pristine ng-valid" action="https://mycustomdomain.com" method="get" 
    name="searchForm"><input autocomplete="off" name="locale" type="hidden" 
    value="en-US" 
    />

    <input autocomplete="off" name="Code" type="hidden" value="[acf field="input"]" 
    data- 
    id="Code" />

    <input id="location" autocomplete="off" name="location" type="hidden" 
    value="property" data-value="property" data-cacheable="true" />
    [row width="full-width" v_align="middle" padding="0 0px 0px 0px"][col span="6" 
    span__sm="12" padding="0 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]
    Check-In Date <input id="checkinDate" autocomplete="off" name="checkinDate" 
    type="text" data-cacheable="true" data-iso-value="" />
    [/col]
    
    [col span="6" span__sm="12" padding="0 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]
    Check-Out Date<input id="checkoutDate" autocomplete="off" name="checkoutDate" 
    type="text" data-cacheable="true" data-iso-value="" />
    [/col]
    [col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="0 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]
    Rooms <input max="2" min="1" name="rooms" type="number" value="1" data-id="rooms" 
    data-value="" data-cacheable="true" />
    [/col]
    
    [col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="0 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]
    Adults <input max="6" min="1" name="adults" type="number" value="2" data-id="adults" 
    data-value="" data-cacheable="true" />
    [/col]
    [col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="0 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]
    Child <input max="4" min="0" name="kids" type="number" value="" data-id="kids" data- 
    value="123" data-cacheable="true" />
    [/col]
    [/row]
    [row width="full-width" v_align="middle" padding="0 0px 0px 0px"]
    [col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="20px 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]
    
    [/col]
    
    [col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="20px 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]
    
    <center><button class="quickbookSearchFormButton button-shop button-block" 
    style="background-color: #ffb612; color: #000; width: 100%; font-size: 16px; font- 
    weight: 400;" type="submit">Book Now</button></center>
    [/col]
    
    [col span="4" span__sm="12" padding="20px 0px 0px 0px" margin="0 0px 0px 0px"]
    
    
    [/col]
    [/row]

    </form>
```

Comment: ACF is not  used to get input from url

Comment: I want to add input to url.

Comment: To get value from ACF in form this tag is not used [acf field="input"]

Comment: Use this function for getting value in input get_field($selector, [$post_id], [$format_value]);

Comment: Thank you. Are you able to apply to apply this answer to my code so I can recheck? I do not know how to apply this php within the WYSIWYG as a short code.

Comment: Switch WYSIWYG from visual to text (or from text to code. Not quite sure how it was.) to edit as plain code.

Comment: You can not apply it from the text editor this function